# Remove on fly over image

Tags: jquery, css, safari, safari6

I am using multiple browsers (IE,Firefox and Safari).

I am not interested in viewing on fly image when drag the  image. Can i disable  the animation on fly image  in all browser using css

```
img{
 user-drag: none; 
 user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

}

and

event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragged, -99999, -99999);}, false);

and `dragged = event.target;
console.log(dragged);
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragged, -99999, -99999);}, false);
entha post la ji`

Comment: add the efforts so far you have given to make it work.

Comment: img{
     user-drag: none; 
     user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}